# Gmail password not visible under Chrome password settings

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, gmail

I used to have a long list of passwords under `chrome://settings/passwords`. For some reason my list now  seems to have become shorted without me having tinkered with it. But the strangest thing is that for instance I can log into my Gmail account without a password, but my Gmail password does not appear under this section of my Chrome browser.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you signed into Chrome?

Comment: Yes I am signed into chrome and can see my google username in the upper-right hand corner. I'm signed into goodle as I opened the browser but the password is not showing under settings.

Comment: Google keeps you logged in to Gmail for "quite a long time" (by default) but might periodically ask for a password - you don't need your password actually stored by the browser for this.

Comment: Well, then where is it stored if not in the browser? Perhaps a cookie (still in the browser, but under cookies rather than under passwords)?

Comment: Hey did you solve it?